# How to upgrade zookeeper from from 3.4.8 to 3.4.13?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying to upgrade zookeeper from 3.4.8 to 3.4.13.

Before upgrade the content of `/usr/lib/zookeeper`

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root 4.0K Aug 23 08:39 .
drwxr-xr-x 77 root root  12K Aug 23 08:50 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Aug 23 08:39 bin
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   19 May 24 11:25 conf -> /etc/zookeeper/conf
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Aug 23 08:39 lib
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  12K May 24 11:25 LICENSE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  170 May 24 11:25 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1.3M Aug 23 08:39 zookeeper-3.4.8.jar
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   38 Aug 23 08:39 zookeeper.jar -> /usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.8.jar
```

As mentioned in [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/758671/300869) I have downloaded the zookeeper from this [link](http://mirrors.fibergrid.in/apache/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.13/zookeeper-3.4.13.tar.gz) and placed the `zookeeper-3.4.13.jar` in `/usr/lib/zookeeper` and pointed the symbolic link like below

```
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root   39 Aug 30 03:19 zookeeper.jar -> /usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.13.jar
```

But on checking the status after resarting zookeeper it is still pointing to 3.4.8

```
ubuntu@vrni-platform:/etc/zookeeper/conf$ telnet localhost 2181
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
status
Zookeeper version: 3.4.8--1, built on 02/06/2016 03:18 GMT
```

It appears this is because of the way the jars are loaded from `/usr/lib/zookeeper/bin/zkEnv.sh`

```
#release tarball format
for i in "$ZOOBINDIR"/../zookeeper-*.jar
do
  CLASSPATH="$i:$CLASSPATH"
done
```

Can someone let me know is this some known issue is `zkEnv.sh`? Is this expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been answered in zookeeper [mailing list](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/How-to-upgrade-zookeeper-from-3-4-8-to-3-4-13-td7583831.html). We should not have multiple `zookeeper-<version>.jar` in the `CLASSPATH`.